# What is the reasoning behind PostgreSQL changing the timezone when changing a timestamp with time zone field?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I have a table with a "timestamp with time zone" column.

For one row, it had this value: `2021-06-24 00:00:00+02`.

Then, I edited and saved it to be: `2021-06-24 11:00:00-05`. Note that both the hour and the timezone has changed.

When I then re-retrieved the value, it was now: `2021-06-24 18:00:00+02`.

In other words, it seems to "prefer" the timezone `+02` and changes any updated values to be in that timezone, even though I changed the timezone to `-05` (because that's the timezone Microsoft gave for their live event). That data is apparently "lost"; seen as unimportant.

Of course, the time is not *wrong* now, but it's *changed* in the sense that it isn't *explicitly* what I changed it to -- just the *local timezone version of that time*.

This confuses me. What is the reason it was designed like this? Wouldn't it be good to retain the timezone and inputted time for each field? Is it hidden/stored somewhere? If I really want that to be stored, do I have to manually make my own columns and handle this manually? For example, if I want to display something in my control panel that points out that this timestamp origins from this or that timezone, etc.?

Comment: It is crucial to understand that the `timestamptz` type (timestamp with timezone) does NOT store timezone data, it stores everything in UTC (and then coverts to whatever you want or settings you have for output)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Note that I'm not talking about output, but only how it's stored. It's confusing since there is also a `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: I know you are not talking about output. Timestamptz does not store timezone, that's the thing to remember (and never use plain `timestamp`). If you want to store the original timezone (or the time offset), you'll need to add another column in the table, along with the timestamptz.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There is nothing wrong with `timestamp without time zone` if you want time zone agnostic behavior (e.g., you manage time zones in your application).

Answer (score 4):

`timestamp with time zone` does not quite meet the expectations of the SQL standard. It should more appropriately be called “absolute timestamp”.

It is stored as microseconds since 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and when converted to a string, it is converted to the time zone indicated by the current setting of the `timezone` parameter in your session.

If you need to retain the original time zone, you will have to store it in an additional column.